# How to secure Symfony app from brute force and malicious traffic

Tags: symfony

I've been looking around but I couldn't find anything useful. What would be the best practice of securing a Symfony app from brute force attacks? I looked into the SecurityBundle but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

Something that I do for this is that I keep a log using event subscribers based on IP addresses and/or usernames attempting to log in. Then, if after an x amount of time an IP/User has tried to log in with a failure then I move that IP address/User to a ban list.. and after that anytime that IP/User tries to log in I deny it right away based on that ban list.

You can also play with the time between attempts and all those goodies inside the event subscriber

Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, I was hoping for a package that comes with all those things out of the box. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Use cloudflare for DDOS attacks. However it may be expensive.

You can prevent dictionary attacks using https://github.com/codeconsortium/CCDNUserSecurityBundle

Comment: It says "NO LONGER SUPPORTED"

Comment: You can grab its logic and build it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I do that with my web/cache server when I need to. I recently used varnish cache to do that with a plugin called vsthrottle. (which is probably one of many things you can use on the server level) the advantage of doing it on the webserver level instead of symfony is that you are not even hitting the php level and compiling all the vendors just to end up rejecting a request, and you are not using a separate data storage (be it mysql or something fast like memcached) to log every request and compare on the next one... If the request reaches the php layer, then it already cost you some performance, and a DDOS of that type will still hurt you even if you are returning a rejection from symfony because it is causing the server to compile php and part of the symfony code.

If you insist on doing it in symfony, register a listener that listens on all requests, parse request headers for either IP addresses or X_forwarded_for (in case you are behind a load balancer in which case only the load balancer ip will keep showing with regular ip check) and then find a suitable way to keep track of all requests up to a minute old (you could probably use memcached for fast storage, with a smart way to increment counts for each ips) and if an ip hits you more than lets say 100 times per the last 1 minute, you return a forbidden response or a too many requests response instead of the usual one... But I do not recommend this as usually built solutions (like the varnish I used) are better, in my case I could throttle for specific routes and not others for example.